How to use arcore Arfragment to get a image in portrait mode
I use arFragment.getArSceneView().getArFrame() to get a frame and save the image.
However, I use my phone in portrait mode, but image is in landscape mode, it seems rotate.
I try to rotate the image before i save it, but i want to know whether i could choose the
orientation.
